# QProcess (net use) does not work

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

I trying to run "net use \server_ip" and parse result. Platform - Windows

I have the following code:

```
QProcess *prc = new QProcess(0);
QString exec="net use";
QStringList params;
params << "\\\\" + getServerIP();
prc->start(exec,params);
qDebug() << "exec process";
prc->waitForFinished();
qDebug() << prc->readAll() << prc->exitStatus();;
delete connected;
```

But readAll() reurns "" and exitStatus() returns 0.

Do you guys have any suggestion?

Comment: `"use"` is actually the first parameter.  The command is `net.exe`

Comment: Also, you should check the result of `QProcess::start`

Comment: QProcess::start returns void

Comment: `QProcess` uses signals to report failure instead of a return value.  Doesn't change that you failed to check the result (result can mean return value, but it can also mean exception, output parameter, global errno, or in this case, a signal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to delete all of the above, and call [WNetAddConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385413.aspx)<sup>1</sup> instead.

At least if I'm interpreting what you have above correctly, it seems to be a really roundabout version of something like this:

```
WNetAddConnection(getServerIP(), NULL, NULL);
```

If GetServerIP returns a QString, you may need to add a call to `toAscii` (or toLatin1, toLocal8Bit, etc.) to convert it to get something `WNetAddConnection knows how to deal with.

---

1. Or `WNetAddConnection2` or `WNetAddConnection3`. Microsoft officially recommends the latter, but you don't seem to need any of the extra capabilities they provide.